# How hard is finding a job as a part-time software developer on a working holiday speaking English in a Nordic country?

Tags: working-holiday

I have an idea of going a year of working holiday in a Nordic country where I understand very little of their language. However the English proficiency there is generally high.

My profession is software development, and my main goal of going working holiday is to learn and train for some sports which require a season of training and are not doable back in my home, most notably ice swimming, while getting a part-time developer job to supplement my travelling cost.

How hard is finding a part-time developer job on working holiday speaking mainly English in a Nordic country? Should I go for it or should I choose an English-speaking country such as Ireland instead?